# how to learn java using just the official apis?

Tags: java, api

I learned php using just the website php.net, but I'm struggling to do the same with Java.
I would like to reach my php level with jsp and generally java, but I find the official docs way too much difficult to read, and if I have a task to accomplish it's quite impossible (to me) without googling and stackoverflowing.
I am wondering if it's normal, or I'm ignoring some secret about the APIs I should know.

I want to make an example: if I have to manipulate a string in a way, I look the PHP manuals for the string functions, and look for the ones I could use reading the brief description I find there.

But if I want to do the same with Java, ok, I know that there's the String class, but there are also an incredible amount of other classes, inherited classes, abstract superclasses, accessories, methods inherited from, interfaces, and I don't know what, that's impossible to read anything (if I'd try perhaps I'll learn Java in the following life).

So I have to rely to manuals websites and google, and find guides and tutorials which describe how to do a particular task (for example, connecting to a Tomcat server and manipulate a DB);

But I don't like to rely to external sources, I would like to find what I need at the source, as I had the experience of my php.net pages which are so precise and full of info and examples.

So? What am I missing?

I am quite sure there's a way to find the right info starting from the api. is it true? and how?

Comment: Type "learn java" into the search box in the upper right of your screen.

Comment: A bit off topic here. Probably a betters fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Already done, and they say I have to use the APIs and the documentations!

Comment: If you want to learn the `String` class, read the `String` API docs. Nothing inherits from `String`, it's `final`. `String` has a single superclass, `Object`. `String` methods take very few argument types, most are `String`, a primitive, or a `CharSequence`--and `String` implements `CharSequence`, so you can use those methods with a `String` argument. Which part is impossible?

Comment: I just pick the example of String.replace and try to understand whether the problem is in finding the method or the description. Are you so kind to clearify? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29

Comment: for a particular method you already know it's ok, but if I'm approaching a new task, and I look for its api, I find impossible to have a broader view of what the classes are meant to do. So I'm for sure missing the right approach, but what's the right approach? If I have to learn the java server faces, your advise is to just read the tutorials?

Comment: The API's are really not a good place to go if you want to expand your knowledge. They should always be treated as a big ole' reference, because thats what they are. If you really want to expand your learning then grab some free lance type projects and start working on them. Nothing expands knowledge like necessity.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Java.

Yes, just for something like reading from a file, you have `java.io` classes for things like `File`, `RandomAccessFile`, `FileReader`, `FileInputStream`, `DataInputStream`, and `BufferedReader` (all slightly different and used for different purposes, often one stacked atop another). Then you have `java.nio`, plus the auxiliary classes like `java.util.Scanner` which are great to have but you need to be aware of first. For any package you'll want to use there's generally an interface, an abstract class, and then a factory to actually manufacture the instance (generally of a third-level derived class) you need to use.

No, reading the JavaDoc is not a great way to learn the language. Java is not as simple as PHP, for whatever reason (the word "enterprise" comes up often, and static safety is a big difference in the language core even without philosophical angles). It has strong advantages, but being able to learn it just from the APIs is not one of those pluses.

You should get a book - I recommend O'Reilly Publishers' products. There are also plenty of decent tutorials on the Internet for the taking. The raw APIs are more "I know which class I want to use, now what methods does it have?".

Comment: Ok I already read O'Really books (you meant Head first Java didn't you? I liked it!), I took all the basics and I definitely know it. I know what is and why I need inheritance, polymorphism, and many other things. But know I have to improve. I'm struggling with jsp and all the servlet stuff.

Comment: @il_maniscalco You may want one of the JSP books, then - knowing the language core is a great start, but now you have to learn the task-specific APIs. The Servlet side of things is generally called "J2EE".

Comment: @il_maniscalco This is also worth saying: a great source of information on how to accomplish a task is how others did it. Reading relevant source code from open-source products is a great way to learn. Just don't copy anything unless you understand the licensing issues :-).

Comment: thanks Borealid, but how to overcome the confusion I feel when I read a code which is using thousand of capital letter Object I never knew, and the same amount of methods? I have to use the Api? Or just use them without being aware of what they really are meant?

Comment: @il_maniscalco Cross-reference the APIs, yes. As time goes on you'll become more and more familiar with the classes involved. It helps if you browse the source in hyperlinked form, so you can just click on a class if you don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using the API unless you want clarification on how a particular object behaves, or how you can best manipulate the object for your purposes.  The reason being, as you said, there are a **lot** of different objects that do very similar things, but with subtle differences.

The API is a reference to information *about* the language; exploring the [Java Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) would be the ideal place to start.

Comment: Again, I already did the Java Trails, I found them ok, I'm not a beginner; but although this, I'm struggling, I know the theory and the basics, but find a bit hard to go on, it seems there are so many objects and so many methods you have to know over there.

Comment: You're not required to use *all* of the objects, nor are you required to *know* them all, either.  It is far better to know the basics and reference objects as necessary - which is why APIs exist.